# How do you use HDMI with the GameCube?

Tags: nintendo-gamecube

The Nintendo GameCube has bad resolution and I want High Definition.

Comment: i just used a HDMI upscaler plug on my Wii however you can by AV/Component HD -> HDMI Upscalers, i use an AV one for the AV Switch  that connects my 2 PS2s and a Component HD one for my PSP. though weather it does any noticiable difference is another issue, i just made everything to HDMI for an array of HDMI Switches so i could run every console from one channel

Comment: I'm also tackling this problem, as well. While I have yet to find if *anyone* has created a specific cable that will allow the GameCube to output in HDMI, I believe that currently the best solution is to use a Component-to-HDMI converter. Of course, there are also hardware mods that allow HDMI, but you risk having an unrepairable GameCube.

Comment: See this: http://lifehacker.com/how-to-connect-your-old-school-video-game-consoles-to-a-1443675453

Answer (score 6):

Apart from internal modification (or through the use of upscalers), the Gamecube does not natively support HDMI. It will support 480p at most through the use of a component cable.

Reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Nintendo_GameCube_games_with_480p_and_16:9_support

and also personal experience.

The official Nintendo Gamecube component cables were discontinued and are extremely hard to find (not to mention expensive when you do come across one). Third-party cables may do the trick; I use a third-party set for my Wii.

Comment: Just to be clear Wii component cables won't work a GameCube. The GameCube are expensive and rare because they require an embedded chip to convert from digital to analogue component video. Aside from homemade cables. I'm not sure if any third party GameCube component cables exist.

Comment: @RossRidge, eBay have a few listings for third party GC component cables, though I don't have a set so I can't test/verify.

Comment: @MikamiHero I'll see if I can still verify this. If I can, I'll post another answer.

Answer (score 1):

This answer will cover the following topics:

1. Why original GameCube component video cables are so expensive.
2. What are the alternatives for getting better video from a GameCube?

**Cost and the Reasons for It**

Original Nintendo GameCube component video cables are running between $150 and $200 on eBay right now. There are 3 reasons for this:

1. There were never very many cables made. In the U.S. the cables were
   only available directly from Nintendo and sales were poor enough
   that in the subsequent revisions of the console, Nintendo removed
   the port for the cable to cut costs.
2. The cable uses a custom connector that doesn't match any of
   Nintendo's other connectors. A Wii component video cable will not
   work wit a GameCube.
3. The cable contains custom integrated circuits that perform the
   conversion from the Digital A/V port's signals to component video.
4. With retro gaming garnering more and more interest and High-Def
   televisions being extremely cheap now, demand for the cables has
   spiked. Three years ago, you could find one for $85. (I can verify
   this because that was the price I paid for mine.)

**GameCube Video Output Alternatives**

You can get a European PAL GameCube, a SCART output cable that plugs into the normal A/V port, and another cable that converts SCART to component video. In NTSC (US and Japan) GameCubes the circuitry for this isn't there, so a SCART cable won't help. There are also some caveats to going this route. One being that the video quality is not as good as the official component video cable. See [RetroRGB - GameCube Output Comparison](http://www.retrorgb.com/gamecubecompare.html) for a good discussion of this.

There are a number of people working on the GameCube video problem. It appears that it's possible to get HDMI or VGA output on a GameCube for about $45 in parts.

There is an Open Source project that has been successfully used to output video from the GameCube at [ikorb/gcvideo: GameCube Digital AV converter - GitHub](https://github.com/ikorb/gcvideo).

On OSHPark, a site where you can buy unpopulated circuit boards, there are 2 projects for implementing High-Def GameCube video:

1. [OSH Park ~ GCVideo Lite 0.9](https://www.oshpark.com/shared_projects/XKoWs6TP)
2. [OSH Park ~ Shuriken Video V2](https://oshpark.com/shared_projects/z5HDKsXc)

The Shuriken Video V2 with the Xilinx xcs200a chip seems to be the best option. Installation requires good soldering skills and some modifications to the case, if you can find someone who has already assembled and programmed the boards. The components are surface mount devices, so you will need the right tools and excellent soldering skills if you must populate the circuit board yourself.

Apparently, a development board called the [Pluto-IIx HDMI](http://www.knjn.com/FPGA-RS232.html) can also be used to do this. I hear that installation is more difficult than the Shuriken.

[madman32ish - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCSSJeIIqxJ0qD-K86LXOkWg) has done a number of videos on GameCube video output clones that are worth checking out to better understand some of this and see actual working examples.

Badass Consoles said it is working on a commercially produced version of the GCVideo as well. See [GameCube - GCVideo - BadAss Consoles](http://www.badassconsoles.com/gcvideo/). This was just announced 1/18/2016 and is not available yet.